# interactivity in Epub used ibooks software of ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, epub, ibooks, epub3

I am used textbox in epub file and view in ibooks software of ipad,but its not properly works,its look like disable.
Do you know an easy way to enable the interaction with html inputs in iBooks for Ipad?

I have a simple epub with html inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1">
```

Comment: Probably some code you wrote in your question was not escaped, and thus the question looks incomplete. Please update if you want any answer.

Comment: As i was worked in ePublishing for many years i got the same issue many time at that time. >>  Input Tags are disabled by default in iBook application for itself(right now have to link to view), Please read iBooks - Publisher User Guide and iBooksAssetGuide which provided by apple for developer account holder - if you have any).